# OpenCV 2.3 in Embarcadero C++ Builder

Tags: opencv, c++builder, compiler-warnings

When compiling a OpenCV 2.3 project in Builder I get multiple errors starting with "_fm_atan2l is not a member of 'std'" and continuing with other math related errors in that form.  I also get "Multiple declaration of '_Ctraits::_Isnan(double)' and other similar errors.  This happens after I simply include the OpenCV header files and thus seems unrelated to anything I have done in the application itself.

The only file I have included so far is "cv.h" in OpenCV's include directory.  Am I doing it wrong already or is there maybe something else I have to set up first?

Comment: what version of builder?

Comment: @berak An old post should be edited if there's something wrong with it.

Comment: If every viewer of the post will vote for official support of OpenCV by C++ Builder, we will have a good chance to get that feature sooner. https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18125

Answer (score 2):

You can download simple project combining 2.3.2 and c++ builder xe2 from my site:
http://www.compvision.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=763
There are fixed headers for builder, and lib converter in archive.
There are also .lib files in archive, but it'll be better if you make them by yourself from original .lib files contained in your opencv distribution using LibConverter.exe utility.
And there is some strange thing: some dll files need to be renamed to something like .dl or .d. Compiled program will prompt you about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can correct `OCV` atan2 issue with `bcc32`, including fastmath in std namespace (for more info see: https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=363384 [^]).... but more other issues are there after ...
Until now I'm unable to build OCV 2.3.1 with CBuilder XE2 :(